# MySQL trigger: error when checking if variable exists

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have a trigger which references a global variable that's coming from a delete query which sets the trigger off:

```
DELIMITER ;;

CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON test_table FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

    IF (SELECT @userID IS NULL) 
    THEN @userID := 0
    END IF;

END
;;

DELIMITER ;
```

For some reason I'm getting SQL error:

```
SQL Error (1064): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '@userID := 0
```

I don't understand this, it's a very basic IF statement, why doesn't it work?

**UPDATE:** I'm totally confused, I've tried this

```
IF TRUE
THEN TRUE
END IF;
```

and it still throws an error... Seriously?

**UPDATE 2: SOLVED** This actually works, however it is very weird

```
IF (SELECT @userID IS NULL) 
THEN SET userID = 0;
END IF;
```

Apparently you need a semicolon inside IF statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER test_trigger BEFORE DELETE ON test_table FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  IF (SELECT @userID IS NULL) 
  THEN 
    SET @userID = 0;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work, but if I put semicolon after 0 it does work. Very weird.